# Why does caniuse.com only list IE8 and IE11 but not IE9 or IE10?

Tags: browser, css

When I look at caniuse.com to check browser support for different properties it lists IE8 and IE11 but not IE9 or IE10.

Why is this? I feel I should test IE9 and IE10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's just hidden by default because global usage has fallen below 0.5%. You can change that threshold under Settings.

https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/2436